# How to find a homomorphic map in following question?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Let $S1$ and $S2$ be two sets. Suppose that there exists a one-to-one
>   mapping $J$ of $S1$ into $S2$ . Show that there exists an isomorphism of
>   $A(S1)$ into $A(S2)$, where $A(S)$ means the set of all one-to-one mappings
>   of $S$ onto itself.

I am not able to find the homomorphic map because $J$ is not necessarily onto.If $J$ was onto we have define a map in which each symbol in an element $x$ belonging to $A(S1)$ could be replaced by corresponding in S2 by using the map $J$.

This Question is from Herstein 2.7.21 .

Comment: I think you are right that it is not true, even with finite sets, if J is not onto. I would assume that J is onto and then do it. Also, sometimes people write "a one-to-one mapping between sets" to mean a bijective map, rather than just an injective map.

Comment: @Keshav This Question is from Herstein 2.7.21 .
No i am sure it's not bijective

Comment: You need to check Herstein's definition of isomorphism. I think "isomorphism of $A(S_1)$ into $A(S_2)$" mean an injective homomorphism from $A(S_1)$ to $A(S_2)$. There is a bijection from $S_1$ to a subset of $T$ of $S_2$, which enables you to construct a bijective isomorphism from $A(S_1)$ to $A(T)$. Then you can embed $A(T)$ into $A(S_2)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I know .But i am not able to do so.Still trying

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you tell me how to embed .

Comment: I think you should be able to do that yourself. It's not difficult.